# Why are my Ruby versions conflicting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, version

When I run `ruby -v` in my `~home` folder, I get:

```
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
```

But now I am trying to run an app, and there are some missing gems. Searching for them, I am told to run this app using Ruby 1.9, but in the /app folder, when I run `ruby -v`, I get:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
```

Why is it so and how can I recover my 2.0. current version of Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you would use some kind of Ruby version management tool like `rvm` or `rbenv`.
These make it possible to have a unique Ruby version for every project (AKA directory), as well as separate gem sets.

Using `rvm` you can switch your current Ruby by running `rvm use ruby-1.8.7`.

Check your project directory using `ls -a` for files like:

- .rvmrc
- .ruby-version

Normally the required Ruby version is selected here and used as soon as you `cd` into the project directory.

Comment: you mean if I want to use a higher version of ruby, I can set it with that command to a specific version, without altering other versions on other projects I have ?

Comment: exacltly that's what these tools are for. And to stick a specific version of ruby to a project, you can include the corresponding hidden configuration file to the project base directory.