# Why do I get this Ruby version conflict?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, configuration, devise, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm starting a new Rails 4 app, and I want to use devise. In my gemfile, I have `ruby '2.1.1'`

If I run

```
ruby -v
```

I get

```
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
```

which is good. This is what I want.

When I run

```
rails g devise:install
```

I get the error `Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.1`.

I've tried running `rvm use 2.1.1` within this gemset with no luck.

I am using the correct gemset for this project, not global or (default).

Comment: Have you taken a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436452/why-are-my-ruby-versions-conflicting?rq=1

Comment: Yes. `rvm use 2.1.1` does not fix the error

Comment: `which rails` are you using? Maybe you've got one that's in your `PATH` from another version. Have you tried `bin/rails g ...`?

Comment: try using `./bin/rails g` as tadman suggested or use `bundle exec rails g`

Comment: bundle exec rails g devise:install gives the same error. 
./bin/rails g devise:install gives 'No such file or directory'